# How to add Editext and Button to Efficent Adapter which has a Icon and text

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-edittext, imageview

I want to create a layout in such a way that on top edittext and button should be there in one row.
 The search text I enter in editext and click on search button. Then I want to display a custom list view where each row contains image and text.(As per the API demos example list14 I have tried). But when I run the application, button and edittext are being added to each row (i.e., Each row contains a image, text, editext, button. Can Any one guide how to resolve this issue.

Below is my xml file:

```
<!--
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"></FrameLayout>
-->
<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon" android:layout_width="48dip"
    android:layout_height="48dip" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<!--
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/prdsearchtb"
    android:text="@string/tb_prd_search_lbl"></EditText>
-->
<!--
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> <TableRow>
-->
<Button android:id="@+id/prdsrcbutton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/btn_lbl_prd_search"
    android:layout_x="2px" android:layout_y="410px"></Button>
<!-- </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

-->

and Java File:
/**
 * 
 */
package org.techdata.activity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * @author jayanthg
 * 
 */
public class ProductSearch extends ListActivity {

```
private static class ProductSearchAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Bitmap mIcon1;
    private Bitmap mIcon2;

    public ProductSearchAdapter(Context context) {

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Icons bound to the rows.
        mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.icon48x48_1);
        mIcon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.icon48x48_2);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return DATA.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        Button btn=null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.productsearch, null);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children
            // views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            btn=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.prdsrcbutton);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
        holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);

        holder.icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("image", " u clicked on icon Position" + position);

            }
        });
        holder.text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Text", " u clicked on text Position" + position);

            }
        });

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Button","U clicked on button");

            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView icon;
    }

    private static final String[] DATA = { "Abbaye de Belloc",
            "Abbaye du Mont des Cats" };

}

ListView product_search_list;
Button srch_btn;
EditText srch_text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ProductSearchAdapter(this));
    // setContentView(R.layout.productsearch);
    // getListView().setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.text));
    // srch_text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.prdsearchtb);
    // srch_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prdsearchtb);
    // srch_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //      
    // @Override
    // public void onClick(View v) {
    // callProductSearchAdapter();
    //
    // }
    // });

}

void callProductSearchAdapter() {
    setListAdapter(new ProductSearchAdapter(this));
}

private void createDialog(String title, String text, final Intent i) {
    if (i == null) {
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(
                R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon).setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                .setTitle(title).setMessage(text).create();
        ad.show();
    }
}
```

}

Regards:
Jayanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is modifying the layout it's using for individual rows, that's why the buttons are appearing on every row. What you need to do is create an XML file for the main layout with the buttons and textviews, and then nest a ListView in it. For example, create a main.xml file like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bla"/>

        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bla"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It's important that the ID of the list view be exactly as above (`@android:id/list`). If you don't use that, your customised 'Efficient Adapter' won't be able to find it. Once you've done that, you just have to add `setContentView(R.layout.main);` to your onCreate method right after the super.onCreate(...) line.

Comment: In response to the OP's post below: You already *are* using a ListView. That's what `setListAdapter(new ProductSearchAdapter(this))` is doing. It's just doing it automatically. The layout I've given you above shows you how to have a TextView and EditText at the top of the list, and then inside your list it can be whatever you want. The list rows can be an image and text or anything else. That's what you define in the XML file for the individual rows that you are inflating with the BaseAdapter's getView.